# Spark streaming join wierd results

Tags: join, apache-spark, streaming

I'm trying to observe how do spark streaming uses the RDDs inside DStream to join two DStreams, but seeing strange results which is confusing.

In my code, I am collecting data from a socket stream, split them into 2 PairedDStreams by some logic. In order to have some batches collected for join, I have created a window to collect last three batches. However, the results of join is clueless. Please help me understand.

```
object Join extends App {

  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("KBN Streaming")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  val BATCH_INTERVAL_SEC = 10

  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(BATCH_INTERVAL_SEC))
  val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 8091)

  //println(s"lines.slideDuration : ${lines.slideDuration}")

  //lines.print()
  val ds = lines.map(x => x)

  import scala.util.Random
  val randNums = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

  val less = ds.filter(x => x.length <= 2)
  val lessPairs = less.map(x => (Random.nextInt(randNums.size), x))
  lessPairs.print

  val greater = ds.filter(x => x.length > 2)
  val greaterPairs = greater.map(x => (Random.nextInt(randNums.size), x))
  greaterPairs.print

  val join = lessPairs.join(greaterPairs).window(Seconds(30), Seconds(30))
  join.print

  ssc.start
  ssc.awaitTermination
}
```

Test Results:

> ------------------------------------------- Time: 1473344240000 ms
>   ------------------------------------------- (1,b) (4,s)
>
> ------------------------------------------- Time: 1473344240000 ms
>   ------------------------------------------- (5,333)
>
> ------------------------------------------- Time: 1473344250000 ms
>   ------------------------------------------- (2,x)
>
> ------------------------------------------- Time: 1473344250000 ms
>   ------------------------------------------- (4,the)
>
> ------------------------------------------- Time: 1473344260000 ms
>   ------------------------------------------- (2,a) (0,b)
>
> ------------------------------------------- Time: 1473344260000 ms
>   ------------------------------------------- (2,ten) (1,one) (3,two)
>
> ------------------------------------------- Time: 1473344260000 ms
>   ------------------------------------------- (4,(b,two))

Answer (score 0):

When join is called, the two RDDs are recomputed again and thus they will contain different values than those shown when printed. So, we need to cache when the both RDDs are computed for the first time and thus same values will be used when join is called later (instead of recomputing both RDDs once again). I tried this on multiple examples and it works fine. I was missing the basic core concept of Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from "Learning Spark" book:

**Persistence (Caching)**

As discussed earlier, Spark RDDs are lazily evaluated, and sometimes we may wish to use the same RDD multiple times. If we do this naively, Spark will recompute the RDD and all of its dependencies each time we call an action on the RDD.